# Take the max value of a column in a sql table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.PRODOTTO, D.CODPROD, D.IDPROD
FROM D_PROD D, APP_SALES S
WHERE D.CODPROD = S.PRODOTTO
```

The result is:

```
PRODOTTO    CODPROD IDPROD

P2  P2  2
P1  P1  1
P3  P3  4
P3  P3  3
```

Now I would the result was

```
PRODOTTO    CODPROD IDPROD

P2  P2  2
P1  P1  1
P3  P3  4
```

with the product P3 that take the max idprod it has encountered.

How can I say to the query to take the max value if there are more rows of one product?

I want the max idprod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.PRODOTTO, D.CODPROD, MAX(D.IDPROD)
FROM D_PROD D, APP_SALES S
WHERE D.CODPROD = S.PRODOTTO
GROUP BY S.PRODOTTO, D.CODPROD
```

Comment: You should never use `distinct` when you have a `group by`.